# Determining wheter a file ends properly with an EOF character

Tags: java, scala, eof

I am dealing with problems caused by files that aren't properly terminated by an EOF character.

How can I detect whether a file contains a proper EOF, and **properly** add it if it is not present in Java / Scala?

Comment: You must have tried something.

Comment: Normally files do not end with any EOF character, in fact no character marks a file's end, you have a confusion here. You can open the file with a hex editor and see if there's any "EOF" character; you will find none.

Comment: can't you just read the last byte of the file and check what it is?  However, I don't think files use EOF chars to mark the end - that's usually console stuff.

Comment: See also https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am dealing with problems caused by files that aren't properly terminated by an EOF character.

Actually, I doubt that that is true.  Off the top of my head, I cannot think of any mainstream operating system where it is necessary terminate a file with an EOF character.  ([This article](https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/) explains the myth of the "EOF character", and why neither ^Z or ^D are EOF characters. Yes, some shells interpret one or the other as EOF "markers" when reading a user input stream via the console, but that is a special case ... and your application certainly won't see the ^Z or ^D when it reads the stream.)

It is possible that you have coded your application to *expect* some kind of EOF character.  If you have, then the best solution is probably to fix the application.  (I can't think of a good reason to design an application to work that way ...)

It is also possible that your real problem is something else.  For example, you may have files where the last line does not end with a recognizable end-of-line sequence.  This is certainly known to cause problems for some classic Linux / Unix utilities.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is the answer to the question you asked.

> How can I detect whether a file contains a proper EOF, and properly add it if it is not present in Java / Scala?

The way to tell if a file does not end with a specific character (e.g ^Z) is to simply read the last character of the file, and test it.  For example, in Java (untested):

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestForArcaneEOF {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Reader reader;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        } else {
            reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int last = 0;
        int ch;
        while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
            last = ch;
        }
        if (last == 0x1a) {
            System.out.println("Ends with ^Z");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Doesn't end with ^Z");
        }
    }
}
```

Adding a character (e.g. ^Z) at the end of a file is even simpler:

1. Open the file in "append" mode.
2. Write the character.
3. Close the file.